# Powershell XML precessing very slow

Tags: powershell, xml

I have a couple (20) of svg-fonts (xml based font format), on average each one of them is about 300kb and contains about 100 Glyph-tags.  I would like to process each glyph with Inkscape. So the part of XML-processing I would like to do with a Powershell script is:

1. Open the font as XML
2. Iterate over each glyph, grab the value of an attribute and save a temp svg (XML) parameterised with this value
3. Process this file with Inkscape
4. Read each of this files
5. Built a new font-file with the new data
6. Save the font, delete the glyph

I have read a lot of Powershell XML tutorials and tried a few times, and there is one thing I do not know what is wrong, but I'm getting each glyph from the font with this line:

```
$nodes = Select-Xml -Content $( Get-Content -Path $_.FullName )  -XPath "//glyph" -Namespace $namespaces
```

needs a lot of time and delivers 60 glyphs, even if their are more in the font. All the rest of the script is working properly, but if I image to process all 20 fonts (will be more in the future) it will take a whole day and not all glyphs are processed.

So, is there a failure in reading the file and parsing the XML? Why is this so incredibly slow and why are not all glyphs processed?

Comment: Do your SVG's have DOCTYPE declarations in them? If so, have you tried removing them to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Hello! removing the DOCTYPE does the trick with the speed, thanks a lot! But still not more than 60 glyphs are processed, even if their are more. Why could that be?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about why it's only processing 60 glyphs.

Comment: could you put a link with some of your files to play with it and search a workaround?

Comment: @voodoomsr i don't know what you mean with: »put a link with some of your files«, could you post a link or something that explains with a little more detail what this approach is about?

Comment: Upload one of the fonts that you use to play with it. Without it it's difficult to test anything. I could generate an XML with the characteristics that you say but is always better having the same file.

Comment: @voodoomsr [here](http://pastebin.com/6sBujsEu) i just didn't checked this simple thing...

Answer (score 0):

Couple options for you:

1. `Select-Xml -Path test.xml -XPath "//*[local-name()='glyph']")`
2. `[xml] $x = gc test.xml ; $x.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='glyph']")`

Both select 95 nodes very quickly. I tested what you put in paste bin.